# linking executable with a full path to the static library

Tags: c++, linker, gnu

i'm linking and building executable against the library in the following way

```
mpic++ -Wall -o example example.o /path/to/my/lib/libmy.a
```

`otool -L example` shows me that it's linked against

```
example:
libmy.a (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
/opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi_cxx.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.1.0)
/opt/openmpi/lib/libmpi.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.3.0)
    ....
```

is there a way to keep the full path in linking? Probably some flag, but i could not find it. 
So that `otool` shows something like:

```
   /path/to/my/lib/libmy.a (...)
   ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, the solution, it seems, is to use:

```
install_name_tool -change "libmy.a" "/path/to/lib/libmy.a" example
```